# How do you get a jQueryUI button click to cause a page redirect?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, redirect, onclick

If I define a jQuery UI button for a search feature:

```
jQuery("#do_search").button();
```

How do I get a click of this button to cause a page redirect to:

```
/search
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use button() on links also

```
<a href="/search" class="button">My link</>
$(".button").button();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
jQuery("#do_search").button().click( function() {
    window.location.href = "/search";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume "do_search" is a  element. If this is the case, clicking the button would simply follow the link, no special action required.

If "do_search" is  or  or something similar, you'd have to write an event handler for the click action. Like:

```
$("#do_search").click(function() { location.href=... });
```

Though I guess that your search page require you to submit some information to it, so the server side code would search it. If this is the case, you'd have to make some modifications to the above code, or use a FORM.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know jQuery UI so much but you could do a redirect in jQuery:

```
$('#do_search').click(function() {
  top.location.href = "/search";
});
```

But if you want to search for what you entered (in a text input field) you could  do:

```
$('#do_search').click(function() {
    var search_value = $("#search_field").val();
    top.location.href = "/search?q=" + search_value;
});
```

...to submit the search.

If this doesn't work try putting the code into:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ... });
```